# What is common practice for handling backend data on eCommerce Confirm Order Page?

Tags: php, e-commerce, logic

I'm seeking some guidance from people with experience in building ecommerce sites. This is actually my first time integrating with a payment gateway.

My implementation is actually a very basic booking system, where user places selects a date and number of tickets to book, clicks checkout and comes to a order confirmation screen, and then upon clicking submit again, user is brought to 3rd party payment gateway.

The 3rd party payment gateway url expects a post submission, containing a few mandatory fields for their api, one of which is a orderID to identify the order.

**This is what I'm doing:**

1. Unique order is generated when the ticket booking page is loaded.
2. User chooses what date he want, # of tickets, and clicks submit.
3. Data is validated, and then saved to a bookings table in db, while the user is brought to the confirmation page, presenting him/her with the details they have chosen and the price.
4. User clicks checkout, and the form is submitted to the 3rd party payment gateway url, user is brought to their page as well to complete payment.
5. Payment is completed, user is brought to our success page, payment gateway also posts details of transaction to a url of our choice which captures the transaction details, and saves it into a orders database.

**So is that feasible ? My questions are:**

1. Should unique order ID be generated as soon as ticket booking page is loaded ?
2. Should I have a booking database that saves bookings on the confirmation page ? What is user never clicks submit, then i'd eventually have a long list of records.. of course we could create some functionality to clean up the table, but is this common practice ?
3. Should I have a temporary booking database as mentioned above, as well as a completed transaction database that only captures transaction details from the payment gateway ? (Regardless of successful/failed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Q1. Should unique order ID be generated as soon as ticket booking page is loaded ?

Ans: No, you should not do it at the time of load. Rather, should do it when the final submit is made for the 3rd Party payment gateway.

Q2. Should I have a booking database that saves bookings on the confirmation page ? What is user never clicks submit, then i'd eventually have a long list of records.. of course we could create some functionality to clean up the table, but is this common practice ?

Ans: Submit the form to your php script and make entry in the database only after submit is clicked. Then you can submit the form to the 3rd party from your php script once the enty has been made into your database.

Q3. Should I have a temporary booking database as mentioned above, as well as a completed transaction database that only captures transaction details from the payment gateway ? (Regardless of successful/failed)

Ans: Not required if followed what mentioned in answer for q2 above.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi NetEmp, thanks for the notes. I had wanted to do it like you said for Q2, i got stuck when i needed to submit it to my controller and then submit to 3rd party url, because 3rd party url expects only a post form submit...

Comment: I guess what i'm asking is, how can I submit 2 forms at the same time on the checkout ? 1 to save to database, 1 to payment gateway ..

Comment: Hi Winterian, you don't need to submit form to two scripts here. Just create a php script and submit the form to it. In this PHP script, first make entry in your database and then send the form details to 3rd Party. For sending details to 3rd party you can use cURL but I guess you want to redirect user to other site. For this, in your same PHP script create pre-filled form (present in container like div which is hidden) and at the botton write javascript code to submit it to 3rd party. This way, you can use the same script for performing the tasks. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks again for the input. I decided to only save the response from the payment gateaway, as I realized they accept additional parameters that you can include in the form submission, and return those parameters upon transaction completion. I did get a javascript solution working like you suggested, but in the end decided against it because its not very reliable for something as important as this.. sometimes old fashioned form submissions are still the best...

Comment: Doing this is good, but then you loose the information of all those users who do go to the payment website but leave it without making payments and don't return back to your website. These can be prospects for your site owner whom he may want to contact later. As for the method not being reliable, could you please share the reason behind why you feel so?

Comment: reason for not reliable, in the unlikely even that javascript is disabled, in certain occasions where jquery/javascript fails to load/intialize because of connection problems, or partial page load, etc. I must however admit, that these are all considered rare occurances.